# Continuous CMS Collections Followed By Concurrent Mode Failure

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory, concurrent-mark-sweep

The GC log for my Java application indicates continuous CMS GC followed by a concurrent mode failure stop-the-world collection that reclaims nearly the entire heap.

**Why are the CMS collections failing to clear the old generation?  Why is a concurrent mode failure stop-the-world collection required?**

CMS collections like the one below occurred continuously for several days before a concurrent mode failure finally forced a stop-the-world collection that cleared space. Notice how the CMS collections recover almost no space, while the collection following the promotion failure reduces the old generation from 1.92 GB to 50.7 MB.

Are the old-generation objects kept alive by dead, uncollected objects in the permanent generation, which are discarded during a STW collection? Should I consider using ‑XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled to address this?

Complete CMS collection in GC log:

```
2014-06-10T22:54:45.999-0700: 4999434.771: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 1920327K(1926784K)] 2050302K(2080128K), 0.3369430 secs] [Times: user=0.34 sys=0.00, real=0.33 secs] 
2014-06-10T22:54:46.338-0700: 4999435.111: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2014-06-10T22:54:50.543-0700: 4999439.315: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 4.204/4.204 secs] [Times: user=4.21 sys=0.08, real=4.20 secs] 
2014-06-10T22:54:50.543-0700: 4999439.315: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2014-06-10T22:54:50.573-0700: 4999439.345: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.023/0.030 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs] 
2014-06-10T22:54:50.573-0700: 4999439.346: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2014-06-10T22:54:54.599-0700: 4999443.371: [GC2014-06-10T22:54:54.599-0700: 4999443.372:    [ParNew
Desired survivor size 8716288 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:    1410440 bytes,    1410440 total
- age   2:     181888 bytes,    1592328 total
- age   3:     117864 bytes,    1710192 total
- age   4:     136792 bytes,    1846984 total
- age   5:     161296 bytes,    2008280 total
- age   6:    2488416 bytes,    4496696 total
: 141989K->5449K(153344K), 0.1317090 secs] 2062317K->1925911K(2080128K), 0.1321970 secs]    [Times: user=0.23 sys=0.01, real=0.14 secs] 
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 2014-06-10T22:54:55.606-0700: 4999444.378: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 2.600/5.033 secs] [Times: user=2.88 sys=0.08, real=5.03 secs] 
2014-06-10T22:54:55.611-0700: 4999444.384: [GC[YG occupancy: 10356 K (153344 K)]2014-06-10T22:54:55.612-0700: 4999444.384: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.1665620 secs]2014-06-10T22:54:55.778-0700: 4
999444.550: [weak refs processing, 0.0000440 secs]2014-06-10T22:54:55.778-0700: 4999444.551: [scrub string table, 0.0010220 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 1920462K(1926784K)] 1930818K(2080128K), 0.1678710 secs] [Times: user=0.28 sys=0.00, real=0.17 secs] 
2014-06-10T22:54:55.780-0700: 4999444.552: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2014-06-10T22:54:57.554-0700: 4999446.326: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 1.775/1.775 secs]    [Times: user=1.82 sys=0.01, real=1.78 secs] 
2014-06-10T22:54:57.554-0700: 4999446.327: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2014-06-10T22:54:57.564-0700: 4999446.336: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.009/0.009 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs]
```

Concurrent mode failure GC log:

```
2014-06-10T22:56:18.793-0700: 4999527.565: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 1920286K(1926784K)] 2051254K(2080128K), 0.3388330 secs] [Times: user=0.33 sys=0.00, real=0.33 secs] 
2014-06-10T22:56:19.132-0700: 4999527.904: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2014-06-10T22:56:23.112-0700: 4999531.884: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 3.976/3.980 secs] [Times: user=4.07 sys=0.04, real=3.99 secs] 
2014-06-10T22:56:23.112-0700: 4999531.885: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2014-06-10T22:56:23.141-0700: 4999531.914: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.022/0.029 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.01, real=0.03 secs] 
2014-06-10T22:56:23.141-0700: 4999531.914: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2014-06-10T22:56:26.242-0700: 4999535.014: [GC2014-06-10T22:56:26.242-0700: 4999535.014: [ParNew2014-06-10T22:56:26.256-0700: 4999535.028: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 1.948/3.114 secs] [Times: user=1.93 sys=0.12, real=3.11 secs] 
 (promotion failed)
Desired survivor size 8716288 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:    1036320 bytes,    1036320 total
- age   2:     825248 bytes,    1861568 total
- age   3:     119024 bytes,    1980592 total
- age   4:     113784 bytes,    2094376 total
- age   5:     129024 bytes,    2223400 total
- age   6:     154976 bytes,    2378376 total
: 141769K->140729K(153344K), 0.3807730 secs]2014-06-10T22:56:26.623-0700: 4999535.395: [CMS
 (concurrent mode failure): 1920816K->50773K(1926784K), 28.3938140 secs] 2062055K->50773K(2080128K), [CMS Perm : 48657K->41071K(262144K)], 28.7750370 secs] [Times: user=1.65 sys=0.03, real=28.78 secs]
```

Java Version:

```
$ /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

JVM Options:

```
-Xms2048m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+PrintClassHistogram
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:HeapDumpPath=<logs dir>
-Xloggc:<log path>
```

Answer (score 0):

Garbage Collection collects the dead objects/null reference. The policy used here is for Low pause. Following are the things that could happened at the application environment

Reason 1:

Application might have used the allocated heap for object allocation which in turns resulted in the shortage of memory in the java heap for further allocation.In this case increasing the Java heap will help in allocating objects for further requests.

Reason 2:

If the set Xmx value is optimum for the application to run then there are possibility to memory leak occurred in the application environment which causes the java heap to occupy with the objects that could not cleared by Garbage collector

Memory Leak could be identified by the following ways.
Add -verbose:gc jvm argument and collect the GC logs. Once the logs are collected load the gc log in the below tool
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/gcmv/
For more information on memory leak refer the below.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memleaks-137499.html